# How to uses dataclass special methods with multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict


@dataclass
class A:
    a: Dict[str, int] = field(default_factory=dict)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.a = {'a1': 0, 'a2': 0}


    def add_key_a(self, key):
        self.a['key'] = 0

@dataclass
class B:
    b: Dict[str, int] = field(default_factory=dict)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.b = {'b1': 0, 'b2': 0}

    def add_key_b(self, key):
        self.b['key'] = 0

@dataclass
class C(A, B):
    pass

user = C()
print(user)
# C(b={}, a={'a1': 0, 'a2': 0})
```

I get an empty 'b' dictionary, but expected to get "{'b1': 0, 'b2': 0}".
I did a search on the Internet and I didn't find a proper explanation and solution to this problem (probably should've search better). So, I ask you guys to help me find out how to solve this problem.

Comment: As with any multiple-inheritance scheme, methods must call their ``super`` equivalent, i.e. ``super().__post_init__``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using multiple inheritance requires classes to be cooperative by calling their `super()` methods in appropriate places. Just like `__init__` should defer to `super().__init__`, `__post_init__` should defer to `super() .__post_init__`.

Since `dataclass`es do not have a common baseclass, deferring to a `super` method must be defensive; `getattr` with a no-op function can be used to skip the super call as needed.

```py
@dataclass
class A:
    a: Dict[str, int] = field(default_factory=dict)

    def __post_init__(self):
        getattr(super(), "__post_init__", lambda: None)()
        self.a = {'a1': 0, 'a2': 0}


    def add_key_a(self, key):
        self.a['key'] = 0

@dataclass
class B:
    b: Dict[str, int] = field(default_factory=dict)

    def __post_init__(self):
        getattr(super(), "__post_init__", lambda: None)()
        self.b = {'b1': 0, 'b2': 0}

    def add_key_b(self, key):
        self.b['key'] = 0
```

---

Naively, one would just use `super().__post_init__()` to call `__post_init__` of the `super` class. But since `dataclass` works via code generation instead of inheritance, the super class is `object` – which has no `__post_init__` method! Thus, the final lookup will fail:

```py
>>> c = C()
>>> super(C, c).__post_init__  # initial __post_init__ used by C instances
<bound method A.__post_init__ of C(b={}, a={'a1': 0, 'a2': 0})>
>>> super(A, c).__post_init__  # second __post_init__ used by C 
<bound method B.__post_init__ of C(b={}, a={'a1': 0, 'a2': 0})>
>>> super(B, c).__post_init__  # final __post_init__ used by C 
...
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__post_init__'
```

The way to fix this is straightforward: just *catch* the `AttributeError` if it occurs and do nothing in that case. We could do that with `try:` `except:` blocks, but there is a terser way.

[The builtin `getattr` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) allows to get an attribute *or a default*. Instead of `a.b`, we can use `getattr(a, "b", default)`. Since we are getting a method to call, a useful default is a callable that does nothing.

```py
>>> lambda : None    # callable that does nothing
 <function __main__.<lambda>()>
>>> # definition | call
>>> (lambda: None)()  # calling does nothing
>>> # getattr fetches attribute/method...
>>> getattr(super(A, c), "__post_init__")
<bound method B.__post_init__ of C(b={}, a={'a1': 0, 'a2': 0})>
>>> # ... and can handle a default
>>> getattr(super(B, c), "__post_init__", lambda: None)
<function __main__.<lambda>()>
```

Putting this in action, we replace the `….__post_init__` with `getattr`. Notably, just as we needed `()` for the call after the `….__post_init__` lookup, we still need `()` for the call after the `getattr` lookup.

```py
super().__post_init__()
#super | method      | call

#      |super |  | method      |  | default  | | call
getattr(super(), "__post_init__", lambda: None)()
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I'm new to OOP, so it is a little bit complicated for me now. But, it seems, I begin to get it better. Thank you for that.

Comment: Oh, actually, I have one more question. I thought I could figure out how `getattr(super(), "__post_init__", lambda: None)()` works but I still don't understand it :(. I didn't find some example with getattr(...)(). This second pair of parentheses really confuse me. Although, I found out that when I delete this parentheses, is seems like the whole string no longer makes any sense. Also lambda: None confuses me a little bit as well. I'm sorry if I'm asking some obvious things to explain, but I'm very new to all this stuff and I can't really find some clear explanation, so I hope you will help me

Comment: @Jeffery-the-newbie That's a bit of a tricky part indeed. I'll expand the answer in a moment.

Comment: Sure, I'll look forward to that.

Comment: Wow, what an amazing explanation: very calm, clean step-by-step explanation! I wish I could upvote your answer more than 1 time. Anyway, you've done a great job. And I'm so thankful to people like that can explain some complicated, at least for me, things or even things that I simply didn't know in such way. Once again, this is wonderful, great chain of explanation of you. Thank you.